# How to buy a used product that requires a United States shipping address?

Tags: cell-phone

I saw a limited series of a product produced by a startup company which offer a unique feature.
The company’s shop website quickly ran *“sold out”* of the limited product.

Then, I tried to find a reseller, and the last one I found is on amazon with only three item remaining in stock. But the product can’t be delivered to France. Of course, I can contact the vendor, but I’m a afraid he’ll be sold out before he start reading his messages.

So how to buy a product that require a ᴜꜱ delivery mail address ?

Comment: I don’t know anyone living in the United States.

Comment: There are a lot of **mailing address providers** that offer paid shipment forwarding from a US address (you bought) to France. Some offer a free trial period or a single item only plan but all of these are not really life hacks but just commercial service providers.

Comment: @Takkat : couldn’t find any of such services. In France, if you want such kind of service, you need to declare you moved and to proof you lived at the past address. So I don’t know such kind of services existed.

Comment: Search Google for `parcel forwarding international` but I can't give you any recommendations.

Comment: Get a **private mail box (PMB)** which will give you a US address qnd will cheerfully forward.  .  You can also get a *registered agent* of the type intended to be a corporation's legal/service address - e.g. Wolters Kluwer/CT Corporations, they're not *for* parcel forwarding but they might work with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be simply in my opinion. You can make use of sites like that:

https://www.viabox.com/

I am not connected with that site or any another but one time i was interested to buy fossil watch from US which was not able to ship outside US. The cons of that type of forwarding is that You probably will be forced to pay a customs fee, and there it can turn out that it is not very affordable. If you are interested in that type of sites You can simply type "virtual US addres" or "US packages forwarding" and there are plenty of sites which can provide You that type of service :)

Comment: I couldn’t bought it https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B01G1NI27M/ref=mp_s_a_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1508365407&sr=8-4&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=freedompop+global+sim&dpPl=1&dpID=51dt6FiNp3L&ref=plSrch

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a scam to get people from the US to respond. I don't exactly know how it will play out, but I have an idea it's like the other scams asking people to do some simple task.

Why don't you fill out the details of your question, OP? Let's see the vendor website and the Amazon link.

Comment: ok : it’s too late https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B01G1NI27M/ref=mp_s_a_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1508365407&sr=8-4&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=freedompop+global+sim&dpPl=1&dpID=51dt6FiNp3L&ref=plSrch

Comment: That's just a link to a FreedomPop SIM kit. That's not an item in short supply, so what are you talking about? Moreover, it _is_ an Amazon link.

Comment: Freedompop global ꜱɪᴍ. Freedompop no longer produce ꜱɪᴍ that can be used outside the United states. Though, it seems there were some ꜱɪᴍ returned to vendor…